# Unity GameObject OnclickEvent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello people I have following class in unity, not attached to anything:

```
public class Path : MonoBehaviour, IPath
{
 public GameObject Quad { get; set; } 
 public Guid Id { get; set; }

 public Path( float sizeX, float sizeY)
 {
     Quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
     Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     Helpers.ChangeSize(Quad, sizeX, sizeY);
 }
}
```

It is called on runtime.

I want to set an OnClick Event on the GameObject Quad (or on  this class) which calls the method of another instace of a class (which is attached to the main camera) and sends its Id to it.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: If it is a MonoBehavior, and it isn't attached to anything, then it *can't* be called. Additionally, you can't have a constructor with parameters because Unity controls the instantiation of components (of which MonoBehaviour extends).

Comment: You are right @Draco18s but there is a workaround - see below in the answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect a click on a game object you'll need to use a raycast whenever the player clicks.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {    
         var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
         RaycastHit hit;

         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) {
             // whatever tag you are looking for on your game object
             if(hit.collider.tag == "Idk") {                         
                 //Call method on camera                      
             }
         }    
     }
```

You'd have to put this into an update method somewhere. Preferably some sort of InputManager. You can read about the Raycast [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)